# Resizable table-cell to shrink smaller than content

Tags: css, jquery-ui, resizable, css-tables

I have set up 2 div tags, the outer one with `display:table` and the inner one with `display:table-cell`. Inside these I have an image.

When I resize the box using jQuery UI's [`resizable()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/) API, I am unable to shrink it smaller than the image.

**Markup**:

```
<div class="resizebox">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/300x60">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.resizebox {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
    width:320px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:table;
}
.resizebox .content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx34f/1/)

I've added another example under the top resizable box to demonstrate the kind of behavior I'm trying to achieve (while keeping the CSS Table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You beat me to it. Just using regular 'ol width: 100%;

```
img {
  width:100%;
}
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx34f/3/)

Comment: Haha, Thanks. I think I'll give this one to you anyway! (when it will allow me to accept)

Comment: Yeah, it all depends on if you want the image to keep expanding with the box past its original size.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, Thanks bud!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following css

```
.resizebox .content img {
   width:100%;
   max-width:100%;
 }
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx34f/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Feeling a big silly now.

Fixed this by adding these CSS Styles:

```
.resizebox img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx34f/2/)